# Getting "Unknown command" error in WinSCP

Tags: sftp, winscp

I'm trying to automate sending a .xlsx file via SFTP using Task Scheduler and WinSCP. I can get WinSCP to launch and successfully authenticate, however it soon after returns the following and closes the connection

```
< 2023-04-03 19:44:36.835 Script: Active session: [1] [redacted]
> 2023-04-03 19:44:36.835 Script: directory of /
< 2023-04-03 19:44:36.835 Script: Unknown command 'directory'.
. 2023-04-03 19:44:36.836 Script: Failed
. 2023-04-03 19:44:36.837 Script: Exit code: 1
. 2023-04-03 19:44:36.837 Closing connection.
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to resolve the unknown command 'directory'.

Task Scheduler Arguments:

```
/script=C:[redacted]Script.txt /log=C:[redacted]Log.txt
```

Script file:

```
# Connect to SFTP server using username and password supplied
open sftp://username:password@[redacted]
# put the TB file(s) stored at the specified path (local directory) to the root
directory of /
# -nopreservetime = swallow a WinSCP error about logging a timestamp on the file
# -resumesupport=off = disable filepart extension to ensure WinSCP transfers the file
without disassembling
# -delete = clears the local directory after the file has been sent, since the future
TB will supersede it
put C:[redacted]\*.xlsx / -nopreservetime -resumesupport=off
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of your comment lines got wrapped somewhere on the way, And as the wrapped parts do not start with `#`, WinSCP tries to interpret them as commands and fail.

It should be:

```
# put the TB file(s) stored at the specified path (local directory) to the root directory of /
# -nopreservetime = swallow a WinSCP error about logging a timestamp on the file
# -resumesupport=off = disable filepart extension to ensure WinSCP transfers the file without disassembling
# -delete = clears the local directory after the file has been sent, since the future TB will supersede it
```